# no resource identifier found for attribute supportsRtl in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I use Cordova for build an Android Application. After I execute `cordova build android --release` command, this error displayed :

> D:\xampp\htdocs\shie_cordova\shia\platforms\android\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:22: error: no resource identifier found for attribute supportsRtl in package android.

AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.shia.main"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:versionCode="10"
    android:versionName="0.0.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity
            android:name="com.shia.main.MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:label="@string/activity_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please more information about your Manifest file

Comment: What information do you need to know?

Comment: the probleme  android:supportsRtl="true", do you need a right to left support ?

Comment: Yes, the language of my project is persian and its RTL!

Comment: You need to declare `android:layout_toEndOf` and `android:layout_toStartOf` to support right-to-left display. in your manifest file

Comment: I deleted `android:supportsRtl="true"` from AndroidManifest.xml and apk was built successfully but the apk file does not install in my phone (my phone android version is 4.4.2 and my project target is 15) .

Answer (score 1):

as you are using android:supportsRtl="true" then your targetSdk must be 17